# Why isnt any obfuscator working with my Javascript code? Is it because of ecmascript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, ecmascript-2016

I cant seem to obfuscate, even when it does get obfuscated it stops working properly and throws error.
obfuscators throw either unexpected token or error at async/await.
here is the code

```
class LedgerElement extends HTMLElement {

__columns = [];//obfuscator throws unexpected token error
__footers = [];
__months = [];

constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
    });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#tmpLedger').innerHTML;
    let parent = this,
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    this.columns = this.getAttribute('cols').split(',');
    this.footers = this.getAttribute('fot').split(',');
    this.status = this.getAttribute('stats').split(',');
    this.months = months;
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getUTCMonth();
    this.currentMonth = months[n];

    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#update').addEventListener("click", async function () {
        await Promise.all([
            getSelectedRows(parent).then((arrList) => {
                arrList.forEach(range => getUpdateData(range, parent, "update"))
            }),
            count = 0,
            calculateTotal(parent)
        ]);
    });

for await/*<-obfuscator throws error*/ (let c of parent.querySelectorAll(`bbl-cell[col="8"]`)) {
    let balanceCell = parseFloat(parent.querySelector(`bbl-cell[row="${c.row}"][col="9"]`).content);
    maxCredit = c.content.length != 0 && c.content == 'YES' ? maxCredit + balanceCell : maxCredit + 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Which obfuscator are you using?  I'm guessing uglify.  Most likely the obfuscator you are using requires the code to be transpiled (with Babel).  class and await syntax aren't supported popular obfuscators

Comment: either transpile with babel or use terser.  also your code has syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're probably using uglify, which does not support ES6+ syntax.  Either transpile it with [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or use [terser](https://try.terser.org/).

Fix your code and put your for await of loop inside an async function, then copy and paste your code here: https://try.terser.org/

Or use the transpiled output of babel with es2015,es2016, es2017, stage-0 presets on to feed to uglify or your obfuscator: [babelified version of your code](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAyCmATA5vATgURPAtvAdgC7TwAehBiMAEgCoCysWuBxA3gFAcD63wA9iACuOfDAC80ANoBdANwB6BfwBGAMyERgYQvzTRCACzT8A7jCH4yAB3jAKiA_wDWBEmhNoe3Nf34U0CWl5bxx-IkMg2TkuATFCNCF7PQAKAEpoTmhs6AghWzR0mJyDQwBLCAA6HUIwYEMAZUMwRDMUrJKcsMR4AC5oAHJ-W3wBjhKAXzTinKMKyohm1tMAJT9CSrL8KzQ6RmhJVuARVkqARyF0AE8G-GxkwoGAYkIcawQUdAG0ze30PdgM2y2GI1jAaFYB1KFQANONOtkwhEogMAFJgfBCcFXAYwwYAMXgKkS2Nxg3o4PqZIGAEFrGgyiBqRScXi0ZZ4NTUUIQKzBjShMhNIRqbdrBQcCovmyAPLJKVoakAOX4ADdcArqQAROwar4hEpzKoCYSiIJGyqoQg0wgJMoqIQUFIDE0Qb4LawgMqEZ0w75A6FVXz-dDm8pVK02u0Op0DXwin4QT3e33--HZC0QWqETRQi2R20MmPwZ1ZnRuxPJn24tOG8OVJFGIKNyIB1Xg6COSRWUzQLU6EvTdPQdv6fBQxCW-CEACqtAAwvRwkYisOLccPKwlxEoS2IFJ8CE1_XFi0zGt_OdLmgbnc7LpHk98ogB-6WogMOqiLAKhQdikACJQDKYBnAAvFICufBgGgDRoMIMpwmgdJMmHEowFMMBvWgAAFEwcAqeBqhAEAUikNCEWgK1bnuBw1nMFIwQhIgfiMAgUhScE0B_LMMnEAA-VDKOE6AuJ4jZfEwOpDBSNAMVQA5BKtGdrBfCh-1qWT5PgPEmNYPEAOfAcALSNIKIRKY4REnIBEsYhJAABis6zoG0EBjnAChaH8MBSL0ljzOgGQh0k0TMO9BQACoAB4AFpVA0LQdD0UoTHMdxPEihRkJBVzoH4NRoH8jYLmuGj7z0GkSJSAADFQVBAWLgDuEApBNcQAIADgAmQatMoSclylRfIxZr5xaqEmIgeB8RAfgdEY8FTlKm9yoeWr6sa5qSKkNKOoAEjYYBKjSiYerawQOoATh6vrKjiP9CCHEocDAUh5whRBsMkY6HtObB8GQIxoAAQkc6AADIIdc-7l0hcRJAGABNDAGgGaAAH5oFe97PuwgBqaBhvAaD4HGkjoH6HGPqQAnoAcmIJmHKZGa4CYgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.6&externalPlugins=)

There are a few other projects like babel-minify, but terser is one of the mature ones.

Comment: I used babel and then obfuscated it but after that it gave me error on run --> Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at sourceMap:45.
sorry if im bothering im new to web development.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-polyfill#usage-in-browser note that although this will work, it is not recommended.  if you choose the babel route you should have full compilation environment set up.  the polyfill is here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-polyfill

Comment: installing babel, includes "prototyping" for deving where you don't need to do compilation:  https://babeljs.io/setup.html#installation   browserify is the easiest to do.  you just need to set up uglifyify babelify chain with browserify and make sure to pass the right preset-envs.  though most people would probably just use a pre-built webpack environment

Comment: (to clarify the babel-polyfill is needed to run the babel transpiled code, regenerator runtime is used by the async/await transpiler)  normally in production use, you should use @babel/polyfill and compile it with your code with tree-shaking to keep the size down

Comment: I got terser running on my ES6 Node code but can't get it to mangle my function names. Any ideas why? I made sure to pass the --module CLI option.